# How to clone Mercurial repository from remote server?

Tags: ssh, version-control, mercurial

How do I clone an Mercurial repository if private key is required for SSH?

I tried following and it does not work.

```
dukeimg@localhost:~/foo/test$ hg clone --ssh -i ~/keys/dukeimg ssh://username@example.com/www/bar/ 
abort: /home/dukeimg/keys/dukeimg: not a Mercurial bundle
```

Comment: And how exactly does it not work? Please provide all output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use a `ssh` command line (`-i`) option with `hg`. It’s not supported. Because `hg` doesn’t support this option, it looks for the repository to clone at `~/keys/dukeimg`.

There are three possible solutions:

1. Use the SSH key agent.
2. [Set Mercurial to use a custom SSH command line](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/pipermail/mercurial/2011-November/040705.html) (`hgrc`):

   ```
   [ui]
   ssh = ssh -i ~/keys/dukeimg
   ```
3. Set the SSH client to use a public key for your host (`ssh_config`):

   ```
   Host example.com
       User my-ssh-user
       IdentityFile ~/keys/dukeimg
   ```

The `--ssh`/`-e` option is meant to be used like this:

```
hg -e 'ssh -whatever -option' ...
```